# lower and upper 3dB frequency from frequency response in Matlab

Tags: signal, frequency, matlab

Is there any Matlab code available to find the lower and upper 3db frequency of a plot. If not what could be the easy way. I am aware of the theory but implementing is becoming difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of off-topic here but the following might help:

```
f3dB = [];
for i = 1:length(V_dB)-1
 if (V_dB(i)<-3 && V_dB(i+1)>=-3) || (V_dB(i)>-3 && V_dB(i+1)<=-3) 
  % found -3dB crossing,.. do linear interpolation:
  df = freq(i+1)-freq(i);
  ddB = V_dB(i+1)-V_dB(i);
  f3dB=[f3dB (freq(i)+(-3-V_dB(i))*df/ddB)];
 end
 if (V_dB(i)<3 && V_dB(i+1)>=3) || (V_dB(i)>3 && V_dB(i+1)<=3) 
  % found +3dB crossing,.. do linear interpolation:
  df = freq(i+1)-freq(i);
  ddB = V_dB(i+1)-V_dB(i);
  f3dB=[f3dB (freq(i)+(3-V_dB(i))*df/ddB)];
 end
end
```

Comment: The command works but it gives only lower 3dB . How to get upper 3dB?

Comment: Updated the answer. I added a bit so it doesn't assume which direction the crossing goes, and linear interpolation. Note that I didn't test it, so no guarantees.